# Transifex missing a string about automatically converting answer to a comment

Tags: bug, status-review, localization, convert-to-comment

When system automatically convert my answer to a comment, I get the string "Your answer has been automatically converted to a comment", untranslated. I wrote a [bug-report](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/13076/532877) in ruSO meta, but a moderator said, that in transifex there isn't such a string.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @αλεχολυτ why did you removed tag [tag:transifex]?

Comment: You can return it if you want, but generally the lack of translatable string is not a problem on transifex side. It's completely a problem on SE side.